# Slice Operators | Catching the 2nd element in every sub list | Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, slice

I have a list of lists, each sub-list contain exactly 2 floats:

```
my_list = [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
```

Is there a one liner slice operation; so as to not have a for loop?

Desired Output:

```
> [[1], [1], [1]]
```

Then, I would like to merge these sub-lists as elements into one list. Outputting, as dtype list:

```
> [1, 1, 1]
```

---

Failed attempt:

```
d_[:][1]
> [[0, 1]]
```

Comment: `[i[1] for i in my_list]` or `list(map(itemgetter(1), my_list))` ([`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter))

Answer (score 1):

You can use [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)

```
ans = [x[1] for x in my_list]
```

Full answer:

```
my_list = [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
ans = [x[1] for x in my_list]

print(ans)

>>> [1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: If it works it works. Thank you :). I wanted to try slicers because I couldn't get a for loop to work, but your solution does work.

Comment: In this case, you are _kind_ of using slice notation anyway, since you are accessing the `n-th` item of a list (in this case, we just specified `n`). Slicing is nice if you want to take a subset of a list, but we really just want a single element :). If this answered your question, remember to accept it so that it can help others as well.